# How can I make a condition where a variable needs to have a range of numbers (lets say from 1 to 10) to be True?

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, variables, integer

Hipertensión1 = S == range(140,159) and D == range(90,99)
So I'm trying to make a project related to the medical field.

I want the systolic value to be between 140 and 159 and the Diastolic value between 90 and 99 for Hipertension type 1 to be True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (140 <= systolic_value <= 159) and (90 <= diastolic_value <= 99):
    hypertension_1 = True
```

Comment: @AnthonyCodno problem, if you can, please set the answer as the accepted one to help future searchers!

Comment: I think I just did that, I am new to this website and learning to use it. I hope I marked it as the correct answer.